# Accessing private C++ methods within C++/CLI wrapper

Tags: c++, c++-cli, private

Given a class method in C++ that has to be private there, how to make C++/CLI access it. Example: C++ class has a private constructor that shouldn't be exposed to the external user, C++/CLI managed code has to have similar private constructor, but internally it must access private C++ constructor to instantiate a member pointer referring to C++ native class.

Comment: Can you edit the C++ class? Can you add a public static factory method?

Comment: There is very little point to this, that C++ constructor is already inaccessible to code that uses your wrapper.  Making it public requires the #pragma make_public hack, you never use it by accident.

Comment: @MatthewMoss - yes I own the C++ class and can make changes. Can you please expand your suggestion?

Comment: @HansPassant, Right, that's the idea that consumers (both C++ and C#) are not able to use the ctor. But CLI has to use it internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind, first of all, the goal of making things inaccessible (i.e. private) generally contradicts the goal of making things accessible. If you're able to change the class declaration, then you have some options. I don't know the specifics of your C++/CLI requirements, but perhaps one of these options will give you what you need.

### Protected and Inheritance

To an "outsider", `private` and `protected` members are equally inaccessible. But to a subclass, `private` is still private while `protected` members are accessible. You can gain access to protected members by subclassing. This can be one way to unit test "private" members of a class without fully exposing it to the world.

```
class A {
protected:  // was private
    int sum(int a, int b);
};

class TestA : public A {
public:
    bool testSum(int expected, int a, int b) {
        return expected == sum(a, b);
    }
};
```

So access to `protected` method `sum` in class A becomes accessible by making it `protected` and subclassing. The private member will remain inaccessible to everything else except subclasses.

### Static Factory Method

You mentioned a private constructor; if you are needing to manage construction, you might accomplish that with a static factory method. For instance:

```
class Foobar {
private:
    Foobar() { }  // Don't let anyone just make one.
public:
    static Foobar* Create() { return new Foobar; }
};

// To create a Foobar instance:
Foobar* pfoo = Foobar::Create();
```

This is not the best interface (better to use a `shared_ptr`, for instance), but it demonstrates my meaning. Note that since the factory function `Create` is public, anyone can create one. However, you can change the body of `Create` to something more complex: include bookkeeping, initialization, etc. The factory method is a way to manage creation, not restrict it. Granted, you may not want this, but it's an option if you need to manage construction.

### Friends

C++ permits giving access of the private parts of classes to other classes/functions via the `friend` keyword.

```
class A {
    int x;  //private
    friend class B;
};

class B {
    void foobar(A& a) {
        a.x = 42;  // permissible, because A declared class B a friend
    }
};
```

Friendship can be granted to another class or to a function. This can easily break encapsulation and make code difficult to follow or keep safe, but it also gives you the means to expose private members to exactly just those who need it.

Comment: Thanks, accepting for the factory, as other two do not apply to described scenario (wrapping native C++ with managed C++/CLI)